# Enabling org-latex in emacs24.5

Tags: macos, latex, org-mode

I am complete beginner trying to set up emacs to work with latex in org mode to generate latex enabled pdfs.

I followed this [link](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/examples/article-class.html) to add latex but i am getting following error on start of my emacs.

This happened after adding the code in the "1.2 Org-mode LaTeX export setup" in my init.el

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "no such file or directory" "org-latex")
  require(org-latex)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/prabhath/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 14780
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/prabhath/.emacs.d/init.el" "/Users/prabhath/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/Users/prabhath/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262 \306=\203\307\310Q\202; \311=\204\307\312Q\202;\313\307\314\315#\203*\316\202;\313\307\314\317#\203:\320\nB\321\202;\316\322\323\322\211#\210\322=\203a\324\325\326\307\327Q!\"\323\322\211#\210\322=\203`\210\203\243\330!\331\232\203\243\332!\211\333P\334!\203}\211\202\210\334!\203\207\202\210\314\262\203\241\335\"\203\237\336\337#\210\340\341!\210\266\f?\205\260\314\323\342\322\211#)\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" (initialization "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'") "~/_emacs" t load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7 "\n\n(fn)"]()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Any suggestions are helpful.

I am using emacs 24.5, org mode > 8.

Answer (score 1):

The link is outdated: there is no such thing as *org-latex.el* any longer. It is also the case that you do not need what that link describes at all.

To export an org file to latex (and thence to PDF), all you need to do is

```
C-c C-e l o
```

The LaTeX exporter is already loaded by default.